# C# Security Token For Authorization

Tags: c#, security, authentication, authorization

I am working on a solution to have an offline approval process between client and server application. If the client is not able to connect to server due to network is down, then server should be able generate a key which will be passed to the client manually by a user. The client should be able to verify code.

Any idea how it could be done?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like Windows when using a Domain. Once you have logged in with Server Connection, the User Profile is cached locally on the Client. So, the next time you can log in without Server Connection. This way there would also be no need of manually keys. Is that a practical way for u?

Comment: No our requirement is specific that there should be an approval request.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a cache of the server token locally and set some sort of end date on the token.

You can cache it in many ways. Like a SQLite, txt or other file with a structure.

In ASP.NET you can cache this way: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/data-access/caching-data/caching-data-in-the-architecture-cs

Make sure to make a scheduler that checks for token and renews by synching it with the server every once in a while.